# PYSPARK set default value in duplicated column name

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

In pyspark, I have a dataframe with 10 columns like this :

```
id, last_name, first_name, manager, shop, location, manager, place, country, status
```

i would like to set a default value to only the first column manager, i've tried with :

```
df.withColumn("manager", "x1")
```

but it gives me an error for ambiguous reference as there is 2 columns with the same name.

Is there a way to do it without renaming the column ?

Comment: You should try and avoid column name ambiguity from the start, you won't be able to write your data otherwise. If you ended up with duplicated column names after a `join`, say between two dataframes `df1` and `df2` you can still access the columns using `df1.manager` and `df2.manager`.

Comment: the data are provided as such and i have to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

One work around can be,to recreate the dataframe changing the column names. It's always better to have unique column names.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('value1','value2'),('value3','value4')],['manager','manager'])
>>> df.show()
+-------+-------+
|manager|manager|
+-------+-------+
| value1| value2|
| value3| value4|
+-------+-------+
>>> df1 = df.toDF('manager1','manager2')

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
>>> df1.withColumn('manager1',lit('x1')).show()
+--------+--------+
|manager1|manager2|
+--------+--------+
|      x1|  value2|
|      x1|  value4|
+--------+--------+
```